# Connecting two android phones over bluetooth for simple app

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm doing a project, and I need to connect two android phones over bluetooth. What I need:

One phone sending out simple commands to the other phone. 
The other phone to receive the command and react accordingly (playing a specific video).

Meaning, that I need to be able to have a set of buttons on the first phone and when pressed, will play a specific video on the other phone.

I have basic experience coding in C#, but have never coded something for an android phone.

How do I start on this project? Is there a library or something you know of, that would help me do the bluetooth connection? I've seen some people use EvoThings, but I'm not sure if you can connect two phones this way.

Comment: If you have experience with C# then I recommend Xamarin as this will alow you to leverage that experience in the Android world.

Comment: do not ask for whole solution for your requirement, show your effort what you have tried, what is problem are you facing,